# Empty cells/rows shows up in/below the bootstrap datatable header

Tags: bootstrap-table

Configuring bootstrap-table using one of sample examples with a few columns, however, additional empty rows/cells show up below the table header, and are part of table header as evident in the elements inspection.

[the rows highlighted below the table header...][image]

Here is HTML snippet creating the table. The data loads ok in the part that is showing no record in the image, and the empty rows are there.

```
 <div id="toolbar">
     <button id="remove" class="btn btn-danger" disabled>
       <i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete
     </button>
 </div>
 <table id="table"
      data-toolbar="#toolbar"
      data-toggle="table"
      data-height="460"
      data-ajax="ajaxRequest"
      data-search="true"
      data-click-to-select="true"
      data-side-pagination="server"
      data-page-list="[10, 25, 50]"
      data-pagination="true"
  >
   <thead>
     <tr>
        <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true" class="checkmark"></th>
        <th data-field="id">ID</th>
        <th data-field="name" data-sortable="true">Name</th>
        <th data-field="email" data-sortable="true">Email</th>
        <th data-field="existing" data-sortable="true">Confirmed?</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
 </table>
```

And, the bootstrap-table.min.css and bootstrap-table.min.js are in the html header.

Any idea what may cause these showing up, and how to fix?

Expect to see only the header rows as per examples on the website (https://live.bootstrap-table.com/example/options/table-ajax.html) with no additional header rows.

**Update**:

After some testing, it seems AJAX call has a role in this. If params.success(res) is set to nothing, i.e., params.success() no additional headers show up. However, with data (even an empty list), those show up.